# What's the type of LazyIO.readFile?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I am trying to find the type of `privacyContents` in

```
privacyContents <- LazyIO.readFile $ markdownPath ++ "PRIVACY.md"
```

Is the type of this variable defined by the return type of LazyIO.readFile? And if the answer is yes, what is the return type of LazyIO.readFile?

Comment: What is `LazyIO`?

Comment: You should tell us what imports are in scope - in particular, what module is `LazyIO` an alias for?

Comment: `LazyIO` could plausibly be `Data.Text.Lazy.IO` or it could be `Data.ByteString.Lazy` or it could be something completely different.  Who knows?

Comment: `:t LazyIO.readfile $ markdownPath ++ "PRIVACY.md"` should indicate that the type is `m something` for some monad `m`, in which case `privacyContents` would have type `something`.

Comment: From my understanding, LazyIO is a package. [link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio) And the import in scope should be `import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LazyIO`

Answer (score 3):

You can have GHC tell you what the type is by using a type hole.

Just add a let statement after the assignment:

```
...
privacyContents <- LazyIO.readFile $ markdownPath ++ "PRIVACY.md"
let _ = privacyContents :: _
...
```

When you compile the program or load it into ghci you will be told what the
type of `privacyContents` is.

My guess is that LazyIO correpsonds to `Data.Text.IO.Lazy` which would make `privacyContents` a lazy Text value (i.e. type Data.Text.Lazy.Text).

Comment: I tried to use `Data.Text.Lazy.Text` as the type of the variable, but error `Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Data.Text.Lazy.Text’` was returned when I compiled the program.

Comment: Did you `import Data.Text.Lazy`?

Comment: Yes, I think I did as `import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LazyIO`

Comment: But did you import Data.Text.Lazy? That is a different module from Data.Text.Lazy.IO. If you are still having trouble you should post a new question.

Comment: I see. I didn't import it at the first time. I just did right now. It seemed to work now. Thanks a lot!